# Why i can't get all details according to user from database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have created a user table in database for user and profile table for more details model like below

Profile.php

```
public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
```

User.php

```
public function profile() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
    }
```

When I call `{{Auth::user()}}` it only giving me the details in user table

> How can i get all details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. You are using Eloquent ORM and for many reasons for example performance, profile won't be automatically loaded from database. But if you need you can display user and his profile like this:

```
{{ dd(Auth::user(), Auth::user()->profile) }}
```

Here I'm using `dd` just to dump and die the content but you are getting the basic idea. I recommend you to read [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) to get the idea how it's working